# Python If statement-differences

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I try to learn the If statement forms integrated with For loop type, and i can't understand the differences between those codes because they give the same result:

```
grade = [100, 97, 73, 56, 78,34]
for i in range(0,len(grade)):
    if grade[i]%2 == 0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+2
    if grade[i]%3 ==0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+3
    if grade[i]%5 ==0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+5
print grade
```

and this:

```
grade = [100, 97, 73, 56, 78,34]
for i in range(0,len(grade)):
    if grade[i]%2 == 0:
        grade[i]= grade[i]+2
        if grade[i]%3 ==0:
                grade[i]= grade[i]+3
            if grade[i]%5 ==0:
                grade[i]= grade[i]+5
print grade
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `if` statements one below another it's possible that something can match one `OR` another.
When you have nested `if` statements, to go through your condition has to match one `AND` another.

Consider in your first case: 10. It will pass `%2 == 0` and `%5 == 0`, but not the `%3 == 0`. In second case it will only pass the first test and won't go to the nested ones.

For instance: `30` will pass all the `if` statements in both case.

Comment: i try it  now- the second case go throe the 3 conditions

Comment: Yes, because you add your 2, 3 and 5 when previous condition matched. In case of `100`, which passed first test, you add `2`, which gives you `102` and pass second test and then gives you `105`, so it passes also third one. It will go through all three `if`s, but not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Both code is same but the main difference is first code contains three if condition that executed top to bottom or one by one and second code contains three nested if condition statement that execute if first statement is true

[learn more from c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/technologies/python)

Comment: Is your answer much different from the accepted answer?